# Do I need separate CXF and Spring MVC apps

Tags: spring-mvc, architecture, cxf, distributed

I am working on a web app that uses, Apache CXF webservices and Spring MVC. Note that these are deployed as 2 separate applications in tomcat. The Spring MVC app only provides a web interface and calls webservices exposed by the CXF application. Now I have been assigned the task to redesign the whole thing. 
The first thing that comes to my mind is to merge the two applications, take out CXF, and just use Spring MVC to avoid the latency introduced by calling CXF webservices from Spring MVC controller.

However there is another aspect that needs to be considered before I do this. There are some webservices that are heavily used than others and in future under heavy load it would be optimal to move these webservices to a separate application to be deployed on a separate server. In that case it would be better to keep the two applications separate and move only those of the CXF webservices to the separate server and get going.

I would like to hear your thoughts on this , to decide on a way to go forward.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of situations can be better handled if the implementation is separated into a library.

Take a simple example of a service that creates full name for a given firstname, lastname. 
Fristly, create a pojo implementation for this

```
public interface NameService {
    public String combineName(String firstName, String lastName);
}

public class NameServiceImpl implements NameService {
    public String combineName(String firstName, String lastName) {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

The above interface and implementation should ideally be in its own package and module. The build, for example, should result in a myapp-service-lib.jar containing the above.

Now lets create a Rest Service for the above.

```
public interface NameRestService {
    public String combineName(String firstName, String lastName);
    ... //any other functions
}

@Path("/person/")
public class NameRestServiceImpl implements NameRestService {

    @Autowired
    private NameService nameService;

    @GET
    @Path("/name/combine")
    public String combineName(@QueryParam("firstname") String firstName, @QueryParam("lastname") String lastName) {
        return nameService.combineName(firstName, lastName);
    }

    ...//other restful implementations

}
```

The above two classes should ideally be in its own module. The build, for example, should result in myapp-web-service.jar/war. This module will use the myapp-service-lib.jar and other service library jars if required.

The above two modules will provide you the flexibility to mix and match the usage and deployment models.
If you want the spring mvc application to directly use the sevice without using the Restful service then just use the myapp-service-lib.jar in the spring mvc app.

If the web service is being deployed separately, it can be done so without any hassles.

Comment: Thanks @Integrator for the great explanation. Could you clarify your statement - 'If you want the spring mvc application to directly use the sevice without using the Restful service'. With Spring MVC you can already expose a rest-like interface through the Spring Controller. In that case what is the need to call another restful service?

Comment: That statement is assuming that you are using the library from some other project not necessarily the current spring mvc.